Error on setup:install at creating database schema
I ran ece-docker command to create a docker-compose file, with the following arguments:
vendor/bin/ece-docker build:compose --root-dir=/var/www --host=localhost --port=80 --mode="developer" --db=5.7 --db-image=mysql:5.7 --expose-db-port=3306 --with-test --php=7.4 --with-xdebug
It generates the following docker-composer.yaml file

version: '2.1'
services:
  db:
    hostname: db.localhost
    image: 'mysql:5.7'
    shm_size: 2gb
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=magento2
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=magento2
      - MYSQL_USER=magento2
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=magento2
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    volumes:
      - '.:/var/www:delegated'
      - 'magento-magento-db:/var/lib/mysql'
    healthcheck:
      test: 'mysqladmin ping -h localhost -pmagento2'
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 3
    networks:
      magento:
        aliases:
          - db.localhost
  fpm:
    hostname: fpm.localhost
    image: 'magento/magento-cloud-docker-php:7.4-fpm-1.3.7'
    extends: generic
    volumes:
      - '.:/var/www:delegated'
    networks:
      magento:
        aliases:
          - fpm.localhost
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
  web:
    hostname: web.localhost
    image: 'magento/magento-cloud-docker-nginx:1.24-1.3.7'
    extends: generic
    volumes:
      - '.:/var/www:delegated'
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    environment:
      - WITH_XDEBUG=1
      - NGINX_WORKER_PROCESSES=1
      - NGINX_WORKER_CONNECTIONS=1024
      - NGINX_SERVER_NAME=localhost
      - NGINX_PHP_UPSTREAM=php-fpm:9000
      - NGINX_ROOT=/var/www/pub
      - NGINX_INDEX=index.php
      - NGINX_ERROR_LOG_LEVEL=error
      - NGINX_CLIENT_MAX_BODY_SIZE=20M
    networks:
      magento:
        aliases:
          - web.localhost
    depends_on:
      fpm:
        condition: service_started
  varnish:
    hostname: varnish.localhost
    image: 'magento/magento-cloud-docker-varnish:6.6-1.3.7'
    networks:
      magento:
        aliases:
          - varnish.localhost
    depends_on:
      web:
        condition: service_started
  tls:
    hostname: tls.localhost
    image: 'magento/magento-cloud-docker-nginx:1.24-1.3.7'
    extends: generic
    networks:
      magento:
        aliases:
          - localhost
    environment:
      - NGINX_WORKER_PROCESSES=1
      - NGINX_WORKER_CONNECTIONS=1024
      - UPSTREAM_HOST=varnish
      - UPSTREAM_PORT=80
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
    depends_on:
      varnish:
        condition: service_started
  test:
    hostname: test.localhost
    image: 'magento/magento-cloud-docker-php:7.4-cli-1.3.7'
    extends: generic
    volumes:
      - '.:/var/www:delegated'
    networks:
      magento:
        aliases:
          - test.localhost
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
  fpm_xdebug:
    hostname: fpm_xdebug.localhost
    image: 'magento/magento-cloud-docker-php:7.4-fpm-1.3.7'
    extends: generic
    volumes:
      - '.:/var/www:delegated'
    environment:
      - 'PHP_EXTENSIONS=bcmath bz2 calendar exif gd gettext intl mysqli pcntl pdo_mysql soap sockets sysvmsg sysvsem sysvshm opcache zip xsl sodium xdebug'
    networks:
      magento:
        aliases:
          - fpm_xdebug.localhost
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_started
  generic:
    hostname: generic.localhost
    image: 'magento/magento-cloud-docker-php:7.4-cli-1.3.7'
    env_file: ./.docker/config.env
    environment:
      - MAGENTO_RUN_MODE=developer
      - 'PHP_EXTENSIONS=bcmath bz2 calendar exif gd gettext intl mysqli pcntl pdo_mysql soap sockets sysvmsg sysvsem sysvshm opcache zip xsl sodium'
  build:
    hostname: build.localhost
    image: 'magento/magento-cloud-docker-php:7.4-cli-1.3.7'
    extends: generic
    volumes:
      - '.:/var/www:delegated'
    networks:
      magento-build:
        aliases:
          - build.localhost
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
  deploy:
    hostname: deploy.localhost
    image: 'magento/magento-cloud-docker-php:7.4-cli-1.3.7'
    extends: generic
    volumes:
      - '.:/var/www:delegated'
    networks:
      magento:
        aliases:
          - deploy.localhost
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
volumes:
  magento-magento-db: {  }
networks:
  magento:
    driver: bridge
  magento-build:
    driver: bridge

At the bin/magento setup:install step, we've got it back:

We must to say we tried with several arguments within the context along, like this:

magento setup:install --base-url=http://localhost:8080 \
--db-host=db --db-name=magento2 --db-user=magento2 --db-password=magento2 \
--admin-firstname=Magento --admin-lastname=User --admin-email=user@example.com \
--admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin123 --language=en_US \
--currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --use-rewrites=1 \
--search-engine=elasticsearch \
--elasticsearch-port=9200
In adittion, there is this error report from php at acessing the app root directory, bound for /pub
Fatal error: Uncaught Zend_Cache_Exception: cache_dir "/var/www/var/cache/" is not writable in /var/www/vendor/magento/zend-cache/library/Zend/Cache.php:209 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/vendor/magento/zend-cache/library/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php(180): Zend_Cache::throwException('cache_dir "/var...') #1 /var/www/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php(86): Zend_Cache_Backend_File->setCacheDir('/var/www/var/ca...') #2 /var/www/vendor/magento/zend-cache/library/Zend/Cache.php(153): Cm_Cache_Backend_File->__construct(Array) #3 /var/www/vendor/magento/zend-cache/library/Zend/Cache.php(94): Zend_Cache::_makeBackend('Cm_Cache_Backen...', Array, true, true) #4 /var/www/vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/Frontend/Factory.php(434): Zend_Cache::factory('Magento\Framewo...', 'Cm_Cache_Backen...', Array, Array, true, true, true) #5 /var/www/vendor/magento/framework/Cache/Frontend/Adapter/Zend.php(45): Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Factory->Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend{closure}() #6 /var/www/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(121): Magento\Framework\Cache\Frontend\Adapter\Zend->__construct(Object(Closure)) #7 /var/www/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(66): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\Framewo...', Array) #8 /var/www/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\Framewo...', Array) #9 /var/www/vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/Frontend/Factory.php(430): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\Framewo...', Array) #10 /var/www/vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/Frontend/Factory.php(176): Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Factory->createCacheWithDefaultOptions(Array) #11 /var/www/vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/Frontend/Pool.php(69): Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Factory->create(Array) #12 /var/www/vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/Frontend/Pool.php(156): Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Pool->_initialize() #13 /var/www/vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/Type/FrontendPool.php(87): Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Pool->get('default') #14 /var/www/vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/Type/Config.php(52): Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Type\FrontendPool->get('config') #15 /var/www/vendor/magento/framework/Cache/Frontend/Decorator/Bare.php(65): Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Type\Config->_getFrontend() #16 /var/www/vendor/magento/framework/App/ObjectManager/ConfigLoader.php(73): Magento\Framework\Cache\Frontend\Decorator\Bare->load('global::DiConfi...') #17 /var/www/vendor/magento/framework/App/ObjectManager/Environment/Developer.php(79): Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager\ConfigLoader->load('global') #18 /var/www/vendor/magento/framework/App/ObjectManagerFactory.php(191): Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager\Environment\Developer->configureObjectManager(Object(Magento\Framework\Interception\ObjectManager\Config\Developer), Array) #19 /var/www/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(212): Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManagerFactory->create(Array) #20 /var/www/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(127): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManagerFactory), '/var/www', Array) #21 /var/www/pub/index.php(27): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create('/var/www', Array) #22 {main} thrown in /var/www/vendor/magento/zend-cache/library/Zend/Cache.php on line 209
The "/var/www/var/cache/" doesn't exists and doens't seems to make sense and Bootstrap try to create "/var/www", which is the current directory and already exists, for the brief.
I'd appreciate.

Please check your mysql service is working correctly, Also have you created a database before running the install command?

Yes, suddenly it tries to connect from internal network, which doens't makes any sense for me. May you enlight wether the mysql image with this envvars sets the configurantion in the docker context? I made an edit for more information.

Ok, it is working and there is a database. I'm newbie on docker, it binds a subnet for each container actually, my mistake sry. However, i still stucked :S

It's solved, the install command must be executed inside of the container. thx
